# Cannot get access to the Jquery JCrop api

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jcrop

I am trying to access to the jCrop api ( http://deepliquid.com ).

Here is my code snippet :

```
// The selected image has been loaded
$('#selectedImage').load(function() {
   var jcrop_api = $('#selectedImage').Jcrop({
                touchSupport:     true,
                onSelect: cropSelected
    });
    jcrop_api.setSelect([ 100,100,200,200 ]);
});
```

I get in the console : 
TypeError: Result of expression 'jcrop_api.setSelect' [undefined] is not a function.

I am aware that I can pass some parameters as options, but I would like to use the api to perform some other stuff (setImage, etc.)

Any ideas ? 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Could you please tell me what is cropSelected? I mean what is the value of cropSelected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the api in the wrong way...

change this:

```
   var jcrop_api = $('#selectedImage').Jcrop({
                touchSupport:     true,
                onSelect: cropSelected
    });
```

to this:

```
   var jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#selectedImage',{
                touchSupport:     true,
                onSelect: cropSelected
    });
```